# PostgreSQL: Can COPY command be used to copy columns from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to copy values from columns in multiple tables to a csv file, not sure if posgres `COPY` command support copying column from multiple tables.

Here's a simplified example of the kind of thing I want to do using the tables below:

```
environment
╔════════╦═══════════╦══════╦══════╗
║ env_id ║ placem_id ║ humd ║ wind ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬══════╬══════╣
║     104║        4  ║   48 ║  119 ║
║     68 ║        9  ║   39 ║  141 ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩══════╩══════╝

placement
╔═══════════╦════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ placem_id ║ loc_id ║  description  ║           date           ║
╠═══════════╬════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║         4 ║     64 ║ description_1 ║ 2019-03-12T20:40:35.967Z ║
║         7 ║      5 ║ description_2 ║ 2019-03-12T20:56:51.319Z ║
╚═══════════╩════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════════════╝

location
╔════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╗
║ loc_id ║    log    ║    lat    ║      address       ║
╠════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╣
║     64 ║ 13.3986   ║ 52.5547   ║ Bosebrucke Einkauf ║
║     71 ║ 21.150122 ║ -6.607044 ║ Charlotte Court    ║
╚════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╝
```

I want to select records from `environment` table and  `location` table using the `placem_id` and `loc_id` in the `placement` table.

It is possible to copy these columns coming from more than one table using the `COPY` function syntax below:

```
\copy products TO '/tmp/products.csv' CSV DELIMITER ','
```

**EDIT:**

I'm interested in columns `humd` and `wind` from `environment` taable; then columns `log` `lat` and `address` from `location` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send a query instead of using the console :

Copy (Select humd, wind, log, lat, address From location natural join placement natural join environment) To '/tmp/test.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',';

Comment: but I'm interested in ONLY selected number of columns not all, i.e, `humd` and `wind` from `environment` table; `log`, `lat` and `address` from `location` table.

Comment: You can use query with set amount of columns instead of '*', even using joins, union, etc, but you will have it as one block, which would be useless, if you want to use the result in restoring data to separate tables.

Comment: @StasShafeev he probably needs a report in csv.

Comment: @arilwan just do what suggested for the columns : specify the columns you need.

Comment: I passed query (using INNER JOIN) to the \COPY command, it works.